# Saving socket.io data per client

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

How would you save data on Socket.io per client? I've thought of this, however  as I'm reading it's probably invalid:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('socket connected');
    var user = {};
    //do stuff with user.

});
```

Does this work normally, or would it mix if somebody else joins? If it doesn't work like it should, then which way does?

Comment: Yes it works.  Is it the best way to do it?  Maybe, maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

What you have creates a closure for each separate connection so it works fine for per socket data that you want to keep in memory.  You would then need to put all other socket communication inside that same closure so that it can access the data too.  The downside to this is that it's hard to get to the data from the outside (which is sometimes required, but sometimes not).

One downside of doing it this way is that the data is temporal and will not last beyond the current connection.  If there's any sort of connectivity or client hiccup and the `socket.io` connected is dropped and reconnects, then a new closure on behalf of the new connection will be created and the original one will be garbage collected when the socket is closed.

Another way that this is sometimes done is to use the `socket.id` as an index into a shared data structure, or if you use any sort of authentication with a userID to use that id as the index into a shared data structure.